# Why >> operator shows different results on different compilers?

Tags: c++, istream

My code shows different results on different IDE's. For an input `1//2` on my IDE it shows the input format error, but on other IDE it throws `DivisionByZero`.

I've tried including `in.peek() == '/'` *even it doesn't make sense to do so* but no avail.

```
struct DivisionByZero : public exception {
    const char * what() const throw() {
        return "Zero Denominator";
    }
};
```

Constructor for **R**

```
R::R(int n, int d)
{
    if (d==0)
    {
        throw DivisionByZero();
    }
    n_ = n * (d / abs(d));
    d_ = abs(d);
}
```

**operator >>**

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, R &r){
    int n, d;
    in >> n;

    if (in.peek() == '/')
    {
        in.ignore();
        if ( (in.peek() < '0' || in.peek() > '9') ){
            in.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
        }
        in >> d;
        r = R(n, d);
    }
    return in;
}
```

**main() code**:

```
R n1, n2;
char op;
try
{
while (cin >> n1 >> op >> n2) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            cout << n1 + n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << n1 - n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << n1 * n2 << endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << n1 / n2 << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch(DivisionByZero& e){
    cerr << e.what();
    return 1;
}
if (cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cerr << "Input format error before '" << char(cin.peek()) <<"'";
    return 2;
}
return 0;
```

**Expected output** : `Input format error before '/'`

**Actual Output** : `Zero Denominator`

Comment: I think showing `// some code` is important here. You are asking whether or not an exception should be thrown but you've shown everything except the relevant part. That is, the part that may be throwing the exception.

Comment: Added more code. Since `in.peek()` has to return `'/'` , `in.setstate(ios_base::failbit)` should work, but its working only on my IDE.

Comment: On what platform and compiler are you getting the undesirable output? How is the input provided (typed manually or piped)? It may be worth eliminating the possibility that the input is not received properly, maybe `//` is being reinterpreted by the shell or something.

Comment: Code is tested on Universities Testing Environment. Input is provided via stdin. The code must pass various test cases, with `1//2 - 1/3` being the input causing this undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`in >> d` fails since characters in the stream can't be parsed as an integer. `d` remains uninitialized. Whatever `R(n, d)` then does with `d` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized object.

Comment: On extraction failure, `istream`s zeroes the value since C++11. The variable is no longer left unmodified. It's only undefined behavior if you are compiling for a version of C++ older than C++11.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't think it's the case if the stream has `failbit` set from the start. And the OP's code explicitly sets `failbit` before attempting extraction.

Comment: why `failbit` isn't being set ? Essentially, `in.setstate(ios_base::failbit);` should execute.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That's interesting. I can't find information either way in that case. It may be that what I wrote isn't applicable here because the failbit was *already* set. I'd be interested if someone could find something on that. I'm looking through the standard but the whole I/O library chapter is not straight forward.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux setting the `failbit` is the actual requirement. If `in.ignore()` ignores the first `'/'` char, then `in.peek()` should return the next `'/'` char, causing `in.peek() < '0'` to become true, setting the `failbit` (which doesn't happen), and upon reading via `in >> d`, it reads the same `'/'` char, causing it to `throw DivisonByZero();` , which is contradicting this whole thing.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux In the actual text of the standard, setting `val` to zero is done by [`num_get::do_get`](http://eel.is/c++draft/facet.num.get.virtuals#3.3.6), not by `operator>>` itself. But, if `failbit` is already set, the [sentry object](http://eel.is/c++draft/istream.formatted.reqmts#1) would notice that and [`operator>>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/istream.formatted.arithmetic#1) won't reach `num_get` calls.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: @RishbhSharma You do set `failbit` - then go right ahead and attempt to read from now-failed stream anyway, and moreover, use the results of that read (guaranteed to fail) in `R` computations.

Comment: On my machine, no attempt is made to read from the stream once `failbit` is set. Could `return in;` after setting the failbit solve the problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `return in;` solved the problem. The question still remains, why on one machine input halts as soon as failbit is set, but continues to read on other.

Comment: On one machine, the uninitialized variable just happens to have the value of `0`, and your program crashes. On the other, it happens to have the value other than `0`, and your program does not crash. Undefined behavior is undefined.